# Landscape first time not load image but portrait do it why?

Tags: android

Mainfest file has this code

```
   android:configChanges="orientation"
```

My Activity also has

```
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setContentView(R.layout.ticket_detail);
       }
```

Two xml for layout-land and layout.
But landscape not load image, image size is 10kb, Is image problem?/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove line  `android:configChanges="orientation"` from your manifest and try 
because this line is for restrict configration change

Comment: Not entirely true, this line in manifest means that you want to handle configuration change by yourself instead of onDestroy -> onCreate sequence